# Cannot GET / Express ERROR

Tags: node.js, express

I am learning `Mean.js` stack, and try to build an app. I have installed Express, and it works. When I tried to configure my static file ( html, js, images, etc.), then things broke.

Here are my files:

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "public"));

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Server running on port 3000');
```

My html file is very simple :

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact List App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Contact List App</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

So when I start the server : `node server.js`, and then I type `http://localhost:3000/` in the browser, I get the "Cannot Get" error.

Where is the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__dirname` doesn't have a trailing slash, so you need to provide one yourself when building the static root:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
                                    ^ this needs to be there
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the route exists. Also, it is a better practice to use path for joining strings. Also, make sure the directory `public` exists and the file `index.html` is inside that folder.

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.html');
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Server running on port 3000');
```