# "Cannot Get /" With Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm getting the error `Cannot Get /` while running my code. I've tried researching and can't really find anything that fits my code. Script:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const roblox = require('noblox.js');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
require('dotenv').config();

roblox.setCookie(process.env.cookie);
const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

app.post('/pass', jsonParser, async(req, res) => {

  let username = req.body.user;
  let userid = await roblox.getIdFromUsername(username);
  console.log('Working!')
  await roblox.setRank(process.env.groupId, userid, "Trainee");
});

let listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, async () => {
    console.log('Your app is currently listening on port: '
                + listener.address().port);
});
```

Comment: There's nothing in your code that tries to do a get request on `/`, and there's nothing in your code that handles that. What do you want to happen when you go to that route?

Comment: I have a script in Roblox that requests it.

Comment: This question is repeated all over stack overflow, before posting a question take a minute to look around

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot GET / Express ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34401822/cannot-get-express-error)

Comment: @SpyingBadge2143, ok something wants to do a HTTP request. Figure out what you want to return, and add a route for `/`

Answer (score 0):

Needed to add this code and it didn't give me the error anymore.

```java
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 res.send('Got');
})
```